# Why do positions of my UI elements change on popViewController?

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder

I recently started using interface builder, the problem i'm facing right now is when i use the `back` button of navigation controller, my UI elements' y axis go up by roughly 20-30 px, is there some setting i've to use to avoid this problem ? And they go up only when i use `pushViewController`, when i use `popViewController` it loads the way i need.

**Code i'm using for pushing:**

```
    examVC=[[ExampleClass alloc] initWithNibName:@"ExampleClass" bundle:nil];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:examVC animated:YES];
```

I'm attaching the images with the question. Please note how label has gone down about 20-30 px.

Why does this happen? What am i doing wrong ?

**Thanks for all the help.**

**Edit : changed the screens for better clarity**

I'm using pushing code on the round rect button.

**Screen 1:UI elements set in my IB**

[image: My UI elements in IB]

**Screen 2: How it looks when pushed from previous view**
[image: Pushed from previous]

**Screen 3: How it looks when popped from the "Next View"**

[image: Popped from the next]

Comment: @iNoob.. the problem isn't with your back or when poped... If you see your xib and the 3rd image which is the view after pop it is the same. So the problem is when you first push the view it shifts the y up.

Comment: @InderKumarRathore Yes i noticed that after your suggestion of adding Navigation bar in the top bar option, any idea why the First screen kind of behaviour is happening ?

Comment: can your post the code where you have pushed the first screen???

Comment: Try with `animation:NO`  i think your navigation bar is pushed after you view...

Comment: one of my friend is going through the same issue, he asked me to post the answer, sorry about unaccept.

Comment: It's all right just accept your answer.... :)

Comment: I've updvoted what ever i found useful though, thanks for "Try with animation:NO i think your navigation bar is pushed after you view." that was useful. Thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My home view controller had the navigation bar hidden, the screen i posted was the second view which comes after the home view. I wanted to hide navigation bar in the first view only, so i had used :

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
     [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
     [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}
```

It caused the problem because i was showing the navigation bar again in `viewDidDisappear`, so the view would load first *then* the navigation bar would be shown causing it to overlap.

So i put the same code in `viewWillDisappear`, which removed the issue. As navigation bar did load before loading of the next view. Now the view loads just like i designed it in interface builder.

Answer (score 1):

Hey I don't know whether it will work for you or 
not but in your IB change top bar `None` to `Navigation Bar`

[image]

**Then adjust your element accordingly and tun the code.**

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but it still doesn't help, my labels are still moving down after the `pop`, i'll edit my question with much clearer image.

Comment: changed the images with your suggestion, its still the same.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of the suggestions here and none of them worked. My UI elements were always lower when popping back to my original view controller. The only thing that fixed this for me was going into my nib file in Interface Builder and turning off Auto Layout.